# Checkbox with ngModel doesn't data-bind correctly with directive when using ng-true-value/ng-false-value

Tags: angularjs

I have a checkbox that's set to an ng:model `foo.bar`. I then have a custom directive that renders a link that should toggle the checkbox. The link updates the model properly, but the checkbox doesn't get checked. Any ideas? The text input has the correct value.

When I remove the `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value` everything works as expected.

HTML:

```
<input type="input" ng:model="foo.bar" />
<input type="checkbox" ng:model="foo.bar" ng:true-value="1" ng:false-value="0" />
<my:directive></my:directive>    
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/tpl.html">
  <a href="" ng:click="toggleModel()">Toggle Value</a>
</script>
```

And the JS:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.foo = {
      bar: 1
    };
})
.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: '/tpl.html',
    link: function($scope) {
      $scope.toggleModel = function() {
        $scope.foo.bar = $scope.foo.bar === 0 ? 1 : 0;
      };

    }
  }
})
```

Working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/kdSB1fPplkseCKw89k6E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `foo.bar` to an integer in your directive but checkbox is using a string.  Best to consistently use strings. So, inside your directive, instead of:

```
$scope.foo.bar = $scope.foo.bar === 0 ? 1 : 0;
```

use this:

```
$scope.foo.bar = $scope.foo.bar === "0" ? "1" : "0";
```

And, inside your controller, switch your init to:

```
bar: "1"
```

[Updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BCBWu9SBtDLg5KB7TztV?p=preview)